# jQuery - Error when combining <select> and checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, select, checkbox

Alright, this code creates a `<select>` and a checkbox:

```
<select id="sel" size="2" onChange="onChange();">
    <option>check</option>
    <option>uncheck</option>
</select>
<input id="cb" type="checkbox"></input>
```

And this is my `onChange()` which is called when the value of the `<select>` is changed:

```
function onChange() {
    // Get the value of the currently selected option.
    var selected = $('#sel').find(":selected").text();
    // Check the box if "check" was selected, otherwise uncheck it.
    $("#cb").attr('checked', selected == 'check'); 
}
```

Now, this works fine *once*. Let's say I choose options in this order:

1. "check"   > checkbox checks
2. "uncheck" > checkbox unchecks
3. "check"   > checkbox doesn't check

So is there something wrong with my code or have i discovered a glitch in the jQuery?

Here's a link to my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Qw7/3/)

Comment: When i use the fiddle, it does not work at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `attr` to `prop` and it will work gr8!

Here is the code:

```
function onChange() {
    var selected = $('#sel').find(":selected").text(); // Get the currently selected option's text value.
    $("#cb").prop('checked', selected == 'check'); // Check the box if option "check" was selected.
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8Qw7/5/)

Answer (score 0):

To be more clean. I removed the onchange handler from the markup and jquery handles the rest. 
Your main issue is you used attr instead of prop

http://jsfiddle.net/M8Qw7/8/

JS

```
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected").text(); // Get the currently selected option's text value.
    $("#cb").prop('checked', selected == 'check'); // Check the box if option "check" was selected.
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>check</option>
    <option>uncheck</option>
</select>
<input id="cb" type="checkbox"></input>
```